# Having difficulty writing correct search for UISearchController filter part

Tags: swift, filter, uisearchcontroller

So here is my data model which I was able to search without UISearchController however

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct events {
    var eventnumber:Int
    var eventname:String
    var swimmers:[heatlane]?
    var expanded:Bool
}

struct heatlane{
    var heat:Int
    var lane:Int
    var age:Int
    var swimmer:String
    var team:String
    var seedTime:String
    var finalsTime:String
}
```

Above is the data structure. I'm trying to figure out the correct filter so that as I type it will only fill the array that contains the partial of swimmers names. In addition I'm not sure how to deal with a clear search bar. When I tap into the

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        print(searchText.lowercased())
 if(searchBarIsEmpty()){
        print("empty search")
        print(self.arrayEV)
        self.filarrayEV = self.arrayEV
        self.eventtable.reloadData()
    }else{
            self.filarrayEV = self.arrayEV.filter({( eachevent : events) -> Bool in
                return (eachevent.swimmers?.contains(where: {$0.swimmer.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}))!
            })
        self.eventtable.reloadData()
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Filter events**:

filter on `swimmer` String with `hasPrefix` , `contains`

```
 let sequence = searchText.enumerated().map{String(searchText.dropLast($0.offset))}

 self.filarrayEV =  self.arrayEV.filter { (event) -> Bool in

                      let allResult = sequence.reduce([heatlane]()) { (result, value) -> [heatlane] in
                        let filter = event.swimmers?.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                            return item.swimmer.lowercased().hasPrefix(value.lowercased()) ? true : item.swimmer.lowercased().contains(value.lowercased())
                        })
                           return result + (filter ?? [])
                      }
                 return allResult.isEmpty == false
             }

   self.eventtable.reloadData()
```

**Search-clear** you can use `UISearchBarDelegate`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        //write other necessary statements
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)

        // Remove focus from the search bar.
        searchBar.endEditing(true) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could explain the text search on top.

Comment: same issue when I type in partial it shows all rows still. are there or not..there appears not to be truly filtering.

Comment: @BostonMacOSX filter result is work with you but clear search not , you need explain for Filter Code , is this true

Comment: So let's say I have "Smith, Tony" in the list of swimmer. As I type "Smi" the entire list stays.If I type "Smq" the entire list disappears. Not the expected behavior as when I type "Smi" I should only see the "Smith, Tony" row. I'll be in car for next 1/2 hr so I may not be able to respond right away

Comment: sorry don't understand what you are saying I have implemented your code with the same result. as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: You need to filter , data with substring matching not complete string so, `Smith, Tony` will be displayed if user type `Smi` or `Smq` because it contain `Sm`. Is that true? I work on

Comment: Ok but EVERY row in array is being returned for Smi and no rows for Smq. Only 1 row show be returned for Smi

Comment: Sorry , Don't understand last message , if you search by  Smq what is result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170964/discussion-between-bostonmacosx-and-abdelahad-darwish).

Comment: @BostonMacOSX now it handel all cases